# Add Static Image Resources in Vue Native

Tags: react-native, vue.js, vue-native

I understand that in order to add static image resources in react native, the images have to be statically known. This is done by:

```
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

In vue native, like in react native, using

```
<image
  :source="{require('./my-icon.png')}"
/>
```

will not work since the static image isn't statically known.
How do I make the image statically known in Vue Native?

Answer (score 2):

In Vue-Native you need to write it like this:

```
<image
:source="require('./my-icon.png')"
/>
```

Drop the `{}` between `""`